# Cannot burn windows 8 iso to DVD in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, iso-image, dvd-burning

I need to burn a windows 8 iso to a DVD in ubuntu 12.04 (installing a bootable USB stick is not an option)

In ubuntu I use brasero and select burn image do disk and select the windows iso (which I have copied to my /home/user dir). The checksum is finished successfully but it fails instantly when it starts to write to the DVD:

[image]

here is the log:

```
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn Something went wrong
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 15
    message = "An error occurred while writing to disc"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : An error occurred while writing to disc (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

I have tried with other blank DVDs but get same result. I know that the iso is not corrupt. Any ideas?

EDIT 1: I get the same problem when I try to burn the ubuntu 13.04 iso image to a DVD

EDIT 2: Using K3B instead fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you tried another burning software?

Comment: It seems that it works with K3B